# Positive LookBehind with Regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I'm trying to get better at regular expressions

I have been trying to write a regular expression that will get a string like this

```
404;http://subdomain.example.com:80/some-path/gallery/name-of-the-brand/23/?id=56&somethingelse=24...
```

And will return

```
http://subdomain.example.com/some-path/gallery/
```

So I'm writing 2 regex expressions to then string them together. I'm sure there is a way to do it all at once, but I don't know it. The first is for the http//subdomain and domain:

```
[http://]+([a-z]+[\.])?[a-z]+[\.][a-z]+
```

Then I'm trying to write one for the /some-path/gallery/ so I took the first one and added the port and tried to use is a lookbehind but I'm not doing it correctly.

```
(?<=[http://]+([a-z]+[\.])?[a-z]+[\.][a-z]+?([0-9-:]+)[/]
```

This is going to run on a Coldfusion server

Comment: Been at the pub so lacking in will and ability to parse your patterns, but to perhaps cut things short: CFML regex doesn't support look behinds at all. CF uses Apache ORO which was discontinued about a decade ago, and simply dun't do look-behinds. Sorry.

Comment: I wish I was at the pub right about now. Regular expressions and I don't mix so well

Comment: I guess what I can do then is use 2 REReplaces. One to take out the port number and one to take out everything after the /some-path/gallery/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
^(\d+[;])?((http:\/\/)([^/:]*))([:]\d+)?((\/[^/]*)(\/[^/]*)\/).*$
```

This regex extracts the (sub)domain and the first 2 folders all nicely grouped into capture group 2 and 6. Below an example:

http://regexr.com/3aaii